# Can not use my USB headset as audio output with audio pulse

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa, headset, kde5

I am currently unable to select my USB Hyper X 7.1 cloud II headset as input and output device. But, if I unplug and reconnect my headset in my computer while it's on, pulseaudio fully recognize my headset and I can set, listen and record without any issue.

On the other hand, if I restart my computer, my OS does not offer my headphones as a choice of output card anymore.

I made attempts to do `pulseaudio -k`, but on very rare occasion my headphones get recognized. I don't know if it matters but I have an error that occurs when I type `pulseaudio --log-level = error`:

```
E: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: pa_pid_file_create () failed.
```

Strangely, my headset can be seen with **lsusb** (B003:D004):

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8009 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 1532:0203 Razer USA, Ltd 
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0951:16a4 Kingston Technology 
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 1b1c:1b2e Corsair 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

If I use **aplay -L**, my headset is also listed:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC892 Analog [ALC892 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Audio [HyperX 7.1 Audio], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I would like to add that if I type alsamixer, I can select my Headset to adjust the volume of the headset's microphone and speaker.

Here is some picture of the GUI in case it might help:

1. [pulse audio output devices (my headset missing)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Grzsx.png) & 2.
   [alsamixer to my headset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYwT7.png)

I do not know much about the audio system on linux so I do not know if I have any other information that I should give you to optimize the possibility of solving my problem. Could it be a bug that I should push on the bug tracker?

I use KDE Neon as the operating system, but I also have Elementary OS + Windows 10 installed and I haveno issue with theses OSes).
Sorry for my english and thank you.