# HyperX Cloud II Headset USB Not Detected

Tags: sound, usb, pulseaudio, alsa

This USB device is not detected on my Ubuntu 20.04 tower. I know the USB dongle, and headset is working, because they work on my laptop which has Pop!_OS 21.04.

On my tower I get this command response with the USB dongle plugged into one of its USB ports, and headset plugged into the dongle:

```
@ubuntu:~$ cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [SB             ]: HDA-Intel - HDA ATI SB
                      HDA ATI SB at 0xfe300000 irq 16
 1 [NVidia         ]: HDA-Intel - HDA NVidia
                      HDA NVidia at 0xfe080000 irq 34
```

No USB device is indicated here. The same command on my laptop does show the presence of the HyperX Cloud II USB Headset.

I know the USB connection to my tower is good because the dongle's LED lights up.

The dongle does appear to be recognized as a USB device:

```
@ubuntu:~$ sudo lsusb
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 011: ID 0951:16a4 Kingston Technology HyperX Virtual Surround Sound
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 04d9:1702 Holtek Semiconductor, Inc. Keyboard LKS02
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 003: ID 1e7d:2e7c ROCCAT 
Bus 008 Device 002: ID 2109:3431 VIA Labs, Inc. Hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

How is this failure to detect it on my tower fixed?

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to include the output of `sudo lsusb`? This will list all of the connected USB devices and their IDs, making it slightly easier to offer a suggestion 

Comment: Done...........

Answer (score 0):

The USB dongle for the headset seems to have some very particular expectations. Based on [information from Linux-Hardware.org](https://linux-hardware.org/index.php?id=usb:0951-16a4) the dongle is detected, but not working in Ubuntu 20.04. That said, people have reported they can get it to work if:

1. They [unplug and re-connect the dongle after every boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/917516/can-not-use-my-usb-headset-as-audio-output-with-audio-pulse)
2. They [install `pavucontrol`](https://askubuntu.com/a/1291124/1222991) and configure the device through the utility

Unfortunately, there is no definitive solution that I can find for this device

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: Thank you for your help :)

pavucontrol is already installed. I have looked for, and have not found, a way to configure in the utility a way to make it work. By utility I assume you mean the GUI that opens when I click on the "PulseAudio Volume Control" in the taskbar.

Replug does not work to get the headphones working on my system.

It appears my only option now is to migrate my tower to Pop!_OS 21.04.

Comment: I migrated my tower's OS from Ubuntu 20.04 to Pop!_OS 21.04. Because the dongle works on my laptop, which also has Pop!_OS 21.04, I expected the dongle would work on my tower after this migration. But it is not the case. Something is missing on my tower's OS. How can I determine what that is?